# Tensorflow: Separating Training and Evaluation Data in TFRecords

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, training-data

I have a `.tfrecords` file filled with labeled data. I'd like to use X% of them for training and (1-X)% for evaluation/testing. Obviously there shouldn't be any overlap. What is the best way of doing this?

Below is my small block of code for reading `tfrecords`. Is there some way I can get `shuffle_batch` to split the data into training and evaluation data? Am I going about this incorrectly?

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
files = tf.train.string_input_producer([TFRECORDS_FILE], num_epochs=num_epochs)

read_name, serialized_examples = reader.read(files)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
  serialized = serialized_examples,
  features={
      'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'value': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
  })
image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.uint8)
value = tf.decode_raw(features['value'], tf.uint8)

image, value = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, value],
 enqueue_many = False,
 batch_size = 4,
 capacity  = 30,
 num_threads = 3,
 min_after_dequeue = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the question was asked over a year ago, I had a similar question recently.

I used tf.data.Dataset with filters on input hash. Here is a sample:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)

if is_evaluation:
  dataset = dataset.filter(
    lambda r: tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast(r, 10) == 0)
else:
  dataset = dataset.filter(
    lambda r: tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast(r, 10) != 0)

dataset = dataset.map(tf.parse_single_example)

return dataset
```

One of the downsides that I have noticed so far that each evaluation may require data traversal 10x to collect enough data. To avoid this you may want to separate data at the data preprocessing time.